# Color DataGrid Row on value in List

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, datagrid

I try to change my code behind to proper binding but i have difficult example.

I try to color row Yellow when Id ( 1st column ) of double clicked row exist in other List ( DataGrid ) like this:
[image]

for now i am doing it quite simple in code behind:

```
private void ColorRow(int idIn)
{
    foreach (RecordTransactionModel item in SelectedMonthDataGrid.ItemsSource)
    {
        if (item.Id == idIn)
        {
            var row = SelectedMonthDataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as DataGridRow;
            row.Background = Brushes.Yellow;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

the best i achived for now in xaml is:

```
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger.Binding>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CultureConverter}">
                            <Binding Path="SelectedItem.Id" />
                            <Binding Path="RecordDetails" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

and Converter:

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    // if both values are not zero ( are both binded )
    if (values[0] != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue && values[1] != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
    {
        List<RecordDetailsModel> list = values[1] as List<RecordDetailsModel>;
        int id = System.Convert.ToInt32(values[0]);

        return list.Exists(x => x.IdIn == id);
    }
    return Binding.DoNothing;
}
```

and ofc it's not working. How to make it work?

EDIT:
For now i figured out workaround that is working but i don't think it is still the proper solution:
I just defined List of objects of 2nd Datagrid inside model of 1st Datagrid and refresh it every change to indicate if id is in list:

```
public List<RecordDetailsModel> RecordDetailsList { get; set; }
public bool IsSelected
{
    get
    {
        if (RecordDetailsList == null)
            return false;
        return RecordDetailsList.Exists(x => x.IdIn == Id);
    }
}
```

and in xaml:

```
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Comment: Why not use the selecteditem setter to flag the records in the other datagrid and then you can color with a converter based on the flags.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. I just tried to add another property that indicate if item exists in that list and change value on it. But in DataGrid i don't have access to ViewModel properties, only to ItemSource 
        public bool ExistInTable
        {
            get
            {
                return RecordDetails.ToList().Exists(x => x.IdIn == SelectedItem.Id);
            }
        }

Comment: when you click on the OTHER datagrid, you can bind that selected value to a property in the viewmodel.  When that property is set, then you can in the viewmodel code set a new property on the list you are trying to color.  Now in the grid with the color you just need to see if that new property is set.

Comment: That's not solving the problem. I want to click on datagrid1 and color rows in this datagrid1 to values that are in datagrid2 and both datagrids have different lists and different models. just have same IDs.